# item["Created By"] - How can I just get the name of the user without their ID?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, object-model

I'm retreiving a series of details from an item using the following (cut down to only include Created By to make this easier to read):

```
public List<FacilitiesEntity> FetchItems(string siteName, string listUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var site = new SPSite(siteName))
                {
                    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        PostEvent("Successfully opened: " + web.Url, BaseExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Debug);
                        PostEvent("Attempting to load list: " + listUrl, BaseExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Debug);

                        return (from SPListItem item in web.GetList(listUrl).Items
                                select LoadItems(item["Created By"].ToString())).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This works great except my usernames are being returned in a format which includes their user ID, for example:

> 323#;Michael

I'm working around this by formatting the list in a string, but surely there's a cleaner solution and a way to just retrieve the users name and not their id alongside it?

Comment: I seem to recall doing something like item["Author"].ID before to get the created by person's ID.

Comment: @PirateEric Thank-you, I'll explore a bit more to see if there's something in that. Gives me a thread to pull on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, item["Created By"].ToString());
if (userValue != null)
{
    SPUser user = userValue.User;
    string name =user.Name;
}
```